# Using GetGlue API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, oauth

I'm trying to use the GetGlue APIs in Javascript.
I've read the API references located at http://getglue.com/api, but I can't connect to the APIs (something with OAuth goes wrong).
I'd like to automatically check in a user to a specific TV show.

Can anyone help me?